# VBScript Regular Expression Split PascalCase

Tags: regex, vbscript

I am using VBScript RegEx

```
Dim RegEx : RegEx = new RegExp
Dim stringValue : stringValue = "StudentID"
Dim NiceName
    With RegEx
        .Pattern    = "([A-Z])(?![A-Z])"
    .IgnoreCase = False
    .Global     = True
    End With

    NiceName=  RegEx.Replace(stringValue ,  " $1")
```

NiceName should be "Student ID"

I am getting "StudentI D"

Note: this pattern is working for strings that do not have two uppercase characters next to each other.

I have tried the following patterns but they generate errors in VBSCript:

```
"(?<!^)([A-Z][a-z]|(?<=[a-z])[A-Z])"
"(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z][a-z])|(?<=[^A-Z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[^A-Za-z])"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not knowing the real requisites, maybe, this could work. Just replace a lowercase letter followed by a uppercase letter with both letters separated with a space

```
Option Explicit

Dim stringValue
    stringValue="the StudentID has a RareCaseOfUpperCASE"

    With New RegExp 
        .Pattern = "([a-z])([A-Z])"
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Global = True
        WScript.Echo .Replace(stringValue, "$1 $2")
    End With
```

Output: `the Student ID has a Rare Case Of Upper CASE`